# Lost color using power shell as git shell for Github Desktop

Tags: powershell, github-desktop

When I use power shell as my git shell for Github Desktop, some colors are missing, some colors have no problem. Here is a short list:

- Still there

  - Posh-Git related
- Missing

  - cmdlet color
  - variable color

Any ideas?

Comment: My github-launched-powershell complains that PSReadLine can't be found, but a normal launch powershell can load that.@MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though @Mathias didn't solve my problem directly, he provided clue for me to finally solve it.

The colored variables feature is provided by module `PSReadLine`. On my device usually I launch a 64-bit version powershell, but somehow Github Desktop choose to launch the 32-bit powershell as a git shell, even I customize it to use 64-bit powershell.exe explicitly.

At last my solution is to install `PSReadLine` in the 32-bit powershell. On my PC it is located in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`, and the command is `Install-Module PSReadline`.